# Handle child component update (controlled vs uncontrolled)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a `Parent` component which container a `Child` component.

- `Parent` supposed to load the data (e.g. using AJAX) and update the `Child` **inputs**.
- `Child` supposed to listen for the changes to its **inputs** and update **them** as well.

Setting `Child` **props** from `Parent` sets **inputs** values:

`<input value={this.props.someVal}`

But this makes it unable to self-update the `child`, since in order to self-update its **inputs** it has to use:

`<input value={this.state.someVal}`

---

Does this mean, `Child` has to listen for input change and triggers `Parents` handler-function that will sets its `props`?

I thought that setting components props - auto-updates corresponding state (triggering re-render) and that using `<input value={this.state.someVal}` should cover both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do it. Smth like (TypeScript syntax):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props: Props) {
  this.setState({
    data: props.data
  })
}
```

This will allow to update the child both from the parent and child itself. Not sure whether this is a right approach, but it kinda works.

Comment: in small apps it's ok, but in bigger apps make sure you are comparing the current props  with the next props,  as react may call componentWillReceiveProps even when the props don't change https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any connection between props and state. These are two different mechanisms: state is internal to the component and used for keeping encapsulated data. Props are sent by an enclosing object, as you've done.

There are several ways to go about this, but the general consensus is that having state in one place and passing it down the component tree leads to less messy code and bugs. That means your statement is correct - you'll have to pass update functions to the child component from the parent, so that when invoked it will re-render the child with new props.

Comment: The idea here, is that the child supposed to encapsulate the logic related to the inputs inside itself (without exposing it to the parent). If one would have 5 different child's sending their data back to the parent for assessment - it will make the app a mess.

Comment: If all the parent is exposing is data and the function to update that data, the way that the child works (the actual input method) is still encapsulated.

Answer (score -1):

Parent component will make the ajax call and set its own state, the state values will be passed as props, which will update the child always.

```
 class parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: null
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.makeApiCall()
  }
  makeApiCall = () => {
    fetch("api_ulr")
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          value: newValue,
        })
      })
  }
  render() {
    return ( < Child value = {
      this.state.value
    } > < /Child>)
  }

}
```

now child will update whenver a new data comes.

Comment: This is exactly what I am using and this doesn't update child's state.

Comment: It will not update child state, you have to setState in componentWillreceiveProps of your child component